# What does the N and E represent in this select statement

Tags: arrays, powershell, select

```
foreach ($computer in $computername) {

      $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer

      $idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName

      $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')

      $group.Members | select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName
}
```

Can someone describe this line? What does the "N" and "E" stand for?

`select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName`

What I want is the output to look like the following and I want to flag the users in the admin group that are NOT apart of our standard setup. Really I want to ignore the SAM accounts that are the domain accounts but flagging them for now works. What is happening is there is a looping through the SAM accounts to create this output. However when the machine is offline I need to make that too.

[image: EXample Output]

Comment: `N` is `Name` and `E` is `Expression` (you can also spell out `Name` and `Expression`). Specifying a hashtable as a parameter to `Select-Object` creates a calculated property. See `help Select-Object` for some examples.

Comment: You are changing your question from what is N and E to a whole other ball game. If you are looking for _changes_ and understanding that is at least another question.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking at the short hand for the key and value of a **calculated property**. "N" is short for *Name*. "L" or *Label* is also used in place of *Name*. "E" of course is for *Expression*.

They are used when you want to manipulate existing properties or as a simple way to add properties. It is by no means the only way.

One of the [Windows PowerShell Tips of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) from TechNet delves into a great example:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\Test | Select-Object Name, CreationTime,  @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}
```

`Length` is in bytes normally. A calculated property is used here to allow for a more human readable number. This is an example of manipulating a property.

In your case it looks like you are taking a list of members and creating output for each member while referencing the server it was attached to. Presumably that information is not normally present, hence the calculated property.

Comment: I could have posted the whole function to make things easier to understand. So the `samaccountName` and the `@{N='Server'; E={$computer}}` will be repated but the `@{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}` will be looping? No that's not it... crap.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that the "E" is shorthand for "Expression" and "N" is "Name"

The expression being the value and Name being the title of in this case the select statement.

Comment: I'm still a little foggy I'm used to the select statement looking like:
`| select Name, Domain, samaccountName`

Comment: @BradleySmith in your case @{n="server";E={$Computer}} the @ starts the change, N="Server" is the name that the output will receive e={$Computer} is the expression used to calculate the output. and for the script that you have the way you listed in the above comment would work just as well in this case, because the way with @{ } is typically used when calculations need to be found such as a date difference or time difference.  Does this help?